# Get status of location providers with Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm using the Google Play Services to get user's location and I can't find a way to get the status of the different location providers (network, gps).

I was looking for some equivalent of `android.location.LocationListener`'s methods.

The point is, I have an activity with a map, it's supposed to display user's location, and if it's not available (because he didn't turn on his gps or whatever), the app prompts a Dialog to ask him to turn on.

Any idea ? :)

Comment: use the LocationManager to check the different providers

Comment: i believe you cant choose the specific provider using the google play services location updates, you'll have to use locationManager like tyczj suggested. you can set the priority with LocationRequest contants. I think it might choose differnt providers according to the constant you choose http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

Comment: and so how do you know that no providers are available and that the user should turn one of them on ?